# Unit tests don't call viewDidAppear method

Tags: ios, unit-testing, bdd, viewdidappear

I am using Specta to create some tests but I don't seem to be able to get this basic one to pass. The app itself works fine but this test won't pass.

**ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self showLogin];
}

- (void)showLogin
{
    [self presentViewController:[ETLoginVC new] animated:NO completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"PresentedVC: %@", [self.presentedViewController class]);
}
```

This logs: `PresentedVC: ETLoginVC`

**Specs**

```
#import "Specs.h"

#import "ETLoadingVC.h"
#import "ETLoginVC.h"

SpecBegin(ETLoadingVCSpec)

describe(@"ETLoadingVC", ^{
    __block ETLoadingVC *loadingVC;

    beforeEach(^{
        loadingVC = [[ETLoadingVC alloc] initWithUserDefaults:nil];
    });

    afterEach(^{
        loadingVC = nil;
    });

    describe(@"no current user present", ^{
        it(@"should have a login view controller as the presented view controller", ^{
            expect(loadingVC.presentedViewController).to.beKindOf([ETLoginVC class]);
        });
    });
});

SpecEnd
```

This fails with: `the actual value is nil/null`

I've tried calling:

`[loadingVC view]`

I've even initiated a `UIWindow` and an `appDelegate` but I just can't get it working.

My view controller is all written in code. No storyboards or nibs.

---

**UPDATE**

For now i've added an `NSString` property that gets updated with the class name that is about to be presented. I then check this string in my test. To get this working though, I had to change my `beforeEach` block to the following:

```
beforeEach(^{
    loadingVC = [[ETLoadingVC alloc] initWithUserDefaults:nil];
    [loadingVC viewDidAppear:NO];
});
```

Although the test passes, I get the following message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <ETLoginVC: 0x7fcf34961940> on <ETLoadingVC: 0x7fcf34961280> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I get that this is because i'm calling `viewDidAppear` before the current view has finished appearing. What I don't get is how I can test this a better way.

I also don't understand why `loadingVC.presentedViewController` still equals nil even with this updated `beforeEach` block.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Changing the `beforeEach` to the below got rid of the warning message and now the `presentedViewController` is set correctly.

```
beforeEach(^{
    mockUserDefaults = mock([NSUserDefaults class]);
    loadingVC = [[ETLoadingVC alloc] initWithUserDefaults:mockUserDefaults];

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.rootViewController = loadingVC;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [loadingVC viewDidAppear:NO];
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `beforeEach` to the following seemed to solve my problem.

```
beforeEach(^{
    mockUserDefaults = mock([NSUserDefaults class]);
    loadingVC = [[ETLoadingVC alloc] initWithUserDefaults:mockUserDefaults];

    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.rootViewController = loadingVC;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [loadingVC viewDidAppear:NO];
});
```